# Card game server side technology, which one to choose?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making card game in C# WPF. For now I have singleplayer mode, and now I need to make multiplayer mode.

This game is for 4 player only. One of them will create game and start server. After that 4 player will connect to the game through game client application. Every player have 60 seconds to play, after that server get notification and then it is other player turn.

Is it okay to be done with web service or would it be better if it is done through TcpListener and TcpClient technology, or perhaps some third option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the players are on the internet I'd go the web service route.  At least you'd want to use http and port 80 to be able to get through firewalls easier.  You wouldn't want your users to have to specifically open up ports just to play the game.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx).